# Output locale strings through function into json

Tags: php, json, function, locale

I'm trying to export a bunch of locale strings into a json object through a function, but it seems like the strings are not being pulled from the .mo file. My code is as follows:

### lang.php

```
<?php

define('_COOKIE_EXPIRE', 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);

$lang = "es";

if(isset($_COOKIE['lang'])){
    $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}

if(isset($_GET['lang'])){
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];
}

define('_LANG', $lang);
setcookie('lang', _LANG, time() + _COOKIE_EXPIRE);

switch($lang){
    case 'es':
        $lc = "es_HN.UTF-8";
        break;
    case 'en':
        $lc = "en_US.UTF-8";
        break;
}

putenv("LC_ALL=$lc");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $lc);
bindtextdomain("messages", "./locale");
bind_textdomain_codeset('messages', 'UTF-8');
textdomain("messages");

?>
```

### functions.php

```
function getProjectsImages(){ 
    //....
    $json = '{Proyectos: [';
    while(...){
    $json .= ($first?'':', ') . '{' .
             'id: ' . $row["id_proyecto"] . ', ' .
             'cliente: "' . $row["nombre_cliente"] . '", ' .
             'portada: "' . $row["portada_proyecto"] . '", ' .
             'actividades: "' . _($row["actividades_proyecto"]) . '", ' .
             'resumen: "' . _($row["resumen_proyecto"]) . '"}';
        if($first) $first = false;
    }
    $json .= ']}';
    return $json;

}
```

All the strings printed through `_("text")`are being printed in spanish even if I've selected the language to be english. Is this the right way to handle locales inside functions?

Comment: You realize there's a `json_encode` function in PHP, right?

Comment: Lol, yeah... I realised I was doing it the long way halfway through, so I thought I'd finish and then change it